# Acer Inspire Windows 8 Pro Product Key

Tags: windows, product-key

My brother took his laptop to be upgraded to Windows 8 Pro.  He received the card with a Product Key on it but then when he went to "Control Panel" and then "Systems", a different Product Key than what was given to him appears.  When he called Best Buy they told him that he should not worry about it.  Is this legal?

Comment: Thanks for all your input, guys!  I told my brother and he is glad for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. It always shows the different number because the "Product ID" displayed is not the same as "Product Key" AKA "CD key" used to install and activate Windows with.

Comment: One easy way to see what 'cd key' was used to install your copy of windows, install a copy of belarc to check : http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html

Answer (score 0):

The product ID shown here is often not the same as the licence key you input.

Even if it means a different key was used to install than was provided then I think it would still be legal; you have an installed copy of Windows and you have a licence for Windows.